# React router master detail setup using nested syntax

Tags: javascript, react-router, reactjs

I'm writing an app that has a master / detail type setup.

I want two different routes:

- `/items` Item listing page (all items)
- `/items/item-slug` Item detail page (single item)

I have the following config:

```
<Route name="app" component={App} path="/">
  <IndexRoute component={ItemList} />
  <Route name="itemList" component={ItemList} path="items">
    <Route name="itemDetail" component={ItemDetail} path=":itemSlug" />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

The listing route works but the item route is never reached (shows listing page instead of item page).

Everything works as expected with the following structure:

```
<Route name="app" component={App} path="/">
  <IndexRoute component={ItemList} />
  <Route name="itemList" component={ItemList} path="items" />
  <Route name="itemDetail" component={ItemDetail} path="items/:itemSlug" />
</Route>
```

... but after reading [react-router's documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md) I was under the impression that I could use nesting to my favour.

Are there any modifications I can make to the first snippet so that the routing works as expected, or is the second snippet the correct way to address this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want to nest `ItemDetail` inside `ItemList`, you can't nest one inside the other. What I would do is something like this:

```
<Route name="app" component={App} path="/">
  <IndexRedirect to="items" />
  <Route path="items">
    <IndexRoute name="itemList" component={ItemList} />
    <Route name="itemDetail" component={ItemDetail} path=":itemSlug" />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<Route name="app" component={App} path="/">
  <IndexRoute component={ItemList} />
  <Route name="itemList" component={ItemList} path="items">
    <Route name="itemDetail" component={ItemDetail} path=":itemSlug" />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Stripping the `items/` path component from the itemDetail route

Answer (score 0):

As you are nesting routes the parent component needs to have the children rendered.

So in `ItemList` component you need to add to the render function `{this.props.children}` to render out `ItemDetail`

so

```
render(){return(<div>{this.props.children}</div>});}
```